# Spring MVC - Strange redirect after a POST request

Tags: java, spring

Good morning all.

My Controller has this method to save into the DB

```
@RequestMapping(value = { path+"/new" } , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveLight(@Valid Luce luce, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return path + "/luce";
        }
        // Add message to flash scope
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("css", "success");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "Luce aggiunta correttamente");
        luceService.saveLuci(luce);
        return "redirect:/"+path+"/"+luce.getIdLuce();
        }
```

`getIdLuce()` is the getter of the model Luce. When i submit the form, the information is sent to the DB correctly, but I'm redirected to /lights/0 as `luce.getIdLuce()` return a 0 (or null) value...

I'm not saving an input value of the `idLuce`, it's a simple auto-increment value

```
@NotNull
@Id
@Column(name="id_luce", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getIdLuce() {
    return idLuce;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your entity object with `@GeneratedValue`. That way, the attribute 'idLuce' will be set when you persist your object.

```
@NotNull
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id_luce", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getIdLuce() {
    return idLuce;
}
```

Comment: forgot to put the OK sign!! Thanks!